# Upon doing a XSL Transform to XML how do I remove white space from a Node's attribute or data?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a part's list built out in XML and each part is labeled as such:

```
<division>
<parts>
    <part number="123456     " drawing="123456    " cad="y">
        <attribute>
            <header>Header</header>
            <list>2</list>
        </attribute>
    </part>
```

And I need to get the data behind the number and drawing attributes without the white space. I tried xsl:strip-space on the specific elements, and across the board, but that only strips the content in between the tags.  I unfortunately have no access to the back-end that's producing the XML, so removing the spaces there doesn't look like an option.

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for two possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use either:**

**[normalize-space](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-normalize-space)()**

or

**[translate](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-translate)`(.,' &#9;&#xA;&#xC;', '')`**

*The first* will eliminate the leading and trailing whitespace in the string, and will also replace any other (inner) whitespace with a single space.

*The second* eliminates all whitespace.